# terminal - Remove background color of text in ls (with oh-my-zsh arrow theme)

Tags: command-line, gnome, ls, zsh

I am using zsh instead of bash in my Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 machine and I'm very frustrated with the background colors when I do `ls` because I can barely read the text.

Here's a screenshot of my terminal.

[image]

I use `oh-my-zsh`'s arrow theme, by the way, which has configurations of:

```
export LSCOLORS="exfxcxdxbxbxbxbxbxbxbx"
export LS_COLORS="di=34;40:ln=35;40:so=32;40:pi=33;40:ex=31;40:bd=31;40:cd=31;40:su=31;40:sg=31;40:tw=31;40:ow=31;40:"
```

I tried changing stuff on the configs above but nothing's working. Is there any way to remove the annoying background color in directories?

Comment: stop giving things 777 permission? ;)

Comment: @Zanna aren't there any workarounds for this? If I'll do that, I'll be changing almost all of my directories' permissions.

Comment: You can probably change the colour yeah, though I don't know how (I will have a look) but there is almost never a good reason for a file or directory to have 777 permission. It's very bad practice to set that.

Comment: As Zanna properly pointed out, your permissions are incorrect. You might want to revise how your partition is mounted.  Apart from that, there's not a lot of what you can do.  You can disable coloring altogether, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the .zshrc but with dircolors. The **easiest** way to come out of this is by installing another [plugin](https://github.com/joel-porquet/zsh-dircolors-solarized%22plugin%22) for ohmyzsh. Follow the steps in readme and for the dark theme, I am not finding any issues.

Hope this helps.